# Mongoose save callback doesn't fire

Tags: node.js, mongoose, sails.js

I'm new to mongoose and I'm having a hard time finding the issue within my code. I'm building a REST server using Sails.js and Mongoose. I have a node module (e.g. "sails-mongoose") for exporting mongoose, where I also connect to my database:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://@localhost:27017/fooria');
module.exports = mongoose;
```

And in my model.js:

```
var adapter = require('sails-mongoose');
var schema = new adapter.Schema({
    firstname: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    }
});
module.exports = {
    schema: schema,
    model: adapter.model('Collection', schema)
}
```

In my controller's create method I have:

```
create: function(req, res, next) {
    var userData = {firstname: 'Test'};
    var users = new Users.model(userData);
    users.save(function(err, data){   
       if (err) return res.json(err, 400);
       res.json(data, 201);
   });
}
```

When running create method, the entry is saved to the Mongodb collection but the callback is never reached. Can someone please help me on this track, as I found similar questions but none helped me though. Thanks!

Comment: Just an FYI: https://twitter.com/ktkaushik/status/380592073482588160

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your are using Express. According Express docs you are calling res.json using incorrect parameters (wrong order).

Correct format:

```
res.json(code, data)
```

Example:

```
res.json(500, { error: 'message' })
```

Comment: I solved this issue. There was an error in my code where I was calling the save method with wrong parameters. The version from the original question is correct though. Also, the problem was that the res.json(data, code) was never reached. And the version of res.json from the original question is correct also. Thanks